# Support for Raphael Javascript library in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javascript, raphael

According to this [blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/javascript_type_inference), Netbeans's supposed to support Javascript type inference. And Javascript support should be built-in to the Netbeans editor.
However when I add an HTML file to a simple Java project, and include the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) javascript library using `<script src="..."/>` it seems that Netbeans does not recognize the library. Even very simple completions, like detecting the new `Raphael` function in the window object are not working.

For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Raphael Play</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'),
        500, 500);
    // no ctrl+space for autocomp Ra -> Raphael
    var candy = paper.set();
    // and of course paper is recognized as Object, no autocompletions for it.
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas_container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Netbeans support, but as far as I know autocompletion (if that's what you need) in JS is only possible by continuously running your code. In Firebug for example you do it by pressing tab in console.

Comment: Read the first link to Sun's blog post. Your statement is incorrect, as in many cases you can use type inference to get the autocompletion data. I think IntelliJ's IDEA does that for Javascript.